How to extract Loki labels from OTLP formatted log messages?
So I have an app that is generated OTLP structured messages and sending them to a collector (we are using Grafana Alloy which is based on the OT Collector).
I am trying to figure out how I can set labels for my messages based on the message content. For example, here is one of my log messages -
{
  "body": "whatever",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "flags": 1,
  "resources": {
    "host.arch": "x86_64",
    "service.name": "MyJavaApp",
  },
  "instrumentation_scope": {
    "name": "com.example.Main"
  }
} 

And I want to create a label for resources_service_name from resources.service.name
So what I have tried is -
loki.process "local" {
  forward_to = [loki.write.local.receiver]
  stage.labels {
    values = {
        my_service_name = "resources.\"service.name\"",
        your_service_name = "resources.service.name",
        whatever_service_name = "service.name",
        some_service_name = "resources_service_name",
    }
  }
}

I've tried a few permutations just to see if I could get any of them to work, and so far none of those are appearing as labels in Loki.
Any ideas?
